# How can we prove this quintic is Calabi-Yau manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, calabi-yau

Is there a simple proof that the following surface is Calabi-Yau? (i.e. it is Kahler and Ricci-flat?)

$$x^5+y^5+z^5+u^5+v^5=0$$

With $(x,y,z,u,v) \in \mathbb{CP}^4$.

Here are my conclusions and you can tell me if I am mistaken:

(1) It is Kähler because it is an analytic equation in complex numbers (?)

(2) If the surface is Ricci flat in $\mathbb{C}^5$ then it is also flat in $\mathbb{CP}^4$ (?) My thought process is that it is a homogeneous equation therefore it is flat in the radial direction (as it is scale invariant). So we can ignore the radial direction in terms of curvature.

If (2) is true then I need to show that the equation is flat in $\mathbb{C}^5$. Taking the real and imaginary parts of the equation gives two equations and the surface is the intersection of the surfaces given by each equation. This does not seem a simple way to calculate the curvature.

Alternatively, I could write the equation as $x=-(y^5+z^5+u^5+v^5)^{1/5}$ and find a complex metric as $g^{\mu\nu}(y,z,u,v)$. But I don't know how I would use this in the normal (real) Ricci tensor equation. Therefor, because it is a complex equation, I can't even use my usual brute force methods to calculate the Ricci tensor.

If it is too hard to show it is Ricci flat, is there a simple way to show at least it is Ricci-scalar flat - which is a less restrictive condition? In general are these surfaces shown to be Ricci-flat by using a metric formulation or by other `tricks'?

**Edit:**
I think I made a mistake by assuming the curvature was to do with how the surface was embedded in $\mathbb{CP}^4$ when really it is only the topology which is important and the question of whether we can put a Ricci-flat metric onto the surface. i.e. the equation above does not necessarily give a flat embedding of the surface even though it may admit a flat metric.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintic_threefold has some info about this

Comment: The proof there hinges on showing that the canonical bundle is trivial. [This article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calabi–Yau_manifold) mentions various equivalent ways that C-Y manifolds can be defined and explains: “By far the hardest part of proving the equivalences between the various properties above is proving the existence of Ricci-flat metrics. This follows from Yau's proof of the Calabi conjecture, which implies that a compact Kähler manifold with a vanishing first real Chern class has a Kähler metric in the same class with vanishing Ricci curvature.”

Comment: Note that proving a Ricci-flat metric exists for this surface is quite different from constructing such a metric. I have no idea whether such a construction is known, but my guess would be that it is not.